# How do we hstack many csr matrices programatically?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.hstack.html#scipy.sparse.hstack

I am vectorizing around 12 text features individually using glove vectors
I am having these 12 csr matrices in a list l

is there a way to stack them all without manually passing each one to hstack function

```
np.hstack(l[0],l[1],.....,l[11])
```

please suggest alternative to this

Comment: maybe simply `hstack(l)`?

Comment: or `scipy.sparse.hstack`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link is to the `sparse.hstack`.  That takes a sequence, a list, of sparse matrices.  That's what your `l` is.

```
 newmat = sparse.hstack(l)
```

The np stack functions also take a list, but shouldn't be used here,